# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client response anidadas

Tags: nodejs, express

Tengo dos res. anidadas y quiero ver cuando encuentra un id responda 200 en un array y si no responder 400 cuando no lo encuentra el id en el array

```
   router.get("/", async function (req, res) {
      for (let index = 0; index < JSON.stringify(recipes.length); index++) {
        const element = recipes[index].id;
        if (await (element == req.params.id)) {
          res.status(200).send("SEE")
        }
        else if (await (element !=  req.params.id)){
          res.status(400).send("NOT_FOUND")
        }
      }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes varios errores de lógica en tu implementación, primero veamos qué quieres hacer con esto:

```
JSON.stringify(recipes.length)
```

Según la documentación del método [stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) del Objeto Global [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) de Javascript, se tiene que:

> El método JSON.stringify() convierte un objeto o valor de JavaScript en una cadena de texto JSON,...

Eso quiere decir que si `recipes` es un `Array`, entonces `length` es un entero, y estarías convirtiendo el entero en una cadena (texto):

```js
let arr = ["0", 1, {prop: "2"}, [3], 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.length));
console.log(typeof JSON.stringify(arr.length));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Todo esto suponiendo que `recipes` es un `Array`, ya que en tu pregunta no se ve de dónde sale la variable `recipe`. Si `recipe` no es un `Array` (o un iterable), no dispone de la propiedad `length`, por lo cual el resultado de invocar una propiedad no definida es simplemente `undefined` y como `undefined` no es un tipo válido para JSON, el método `stringify()` devuelve `undefined`:

```js
let recipe = {prop: "value"} // No es un iterable
console.log(JSON.stringify(recipe.length));
console.log(typeof JSON.stringify(recipe.length));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Así, no deberías usar `JSON.stringify` si vas a usar la propiedad `length` de un iterable para comparación dentro de un bucle.

Luego, en tu bucle tienes un llamado a `res` si el elemento está dentro de tu `Array` de recipes y otro llamado a `res` en caso contrario. Estas llamadas se realizan por cada elemento de tu `Array`, y es lo que provoca el `error` en tu programa, ya que una respuesta `http` sólo puede enviarse 1 vez, y tu código envía una respuesta por cada elemento.

Lo que no me queda claro es ¿porqué usas `async / await`? La búsqueda en un `Array` no es asíncrona, por lo cual estás convirtiendo código síncrono en código asíncrono para nada.

Los tipo [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) de Javascript disponen del método [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), que podrías aplicar perfectamente en este caso:

```js
router.get("/", function (req, res) { // no necesitas async en este código particular
  let filtered = recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.id === req.params.id);
  if (filtered.length) return res.status(200).json({message: 'Found'});
  return res.status(404).json({message: 'Not found'});
});
```

En el código anterior, estoy filtrando el `Array` de recipes y devolviendo sólo los elementos cuyo campo `id` coincidan con el valor de `req.params.id`. Luego simplemente inspecciono el tamaño del `Array` resultante.

Un tamaño mayor que 0 indica que se encontró al menos 1 coincidencia, por lo cual puedo devolver el mensaje `Found` al cliente.

Un tamaño igual a 0 indica que no se encontró coincidencia, por lo cual devuelvo `Not found`.

Como puedes observar, en ambos casos uso la sentencia `return`, si bien en la última línea no parece necesario, es una buena práctica usarla cada vez que trabajes con respuestas `http`.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 3):

El error ocurre cuando tratas de responder a la petición mas de una vez, es decir, usas `res.send()` dos o mas veces.

Por definición cada ruta sólo debe ser respondida una vez, para esto puedes usar un valor booleano para recorrer tu arreglo y luego dejar el `if` con las respuestas luego del ciclo.

```
router.get("/", async function (req, res) {
      let estaEnArreglo = false // suponemos que no está en el arreglo
      for (let index = 0; index < recipes.length; index++) {
        const element = recipes[index].id;
        if (element == req.params.id) {
          estaEnArreglo = true //lo encontramos
          break; //nos salimos del ciclo, pues ya lo encontramos
        }
      }
      if(estaEnArreglo) res.status(200).send("SEE") // respondemos que sí está
      else res.status(400).send("NOT_FOUND") //respondemos que no está


});
```